# syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'

Tags: php, syntax

I've got a problem when I'm calling a static var from another class. I get this pretty syntax error where php is unexpected the '.'

Here is where I'm calling it :

```
private $aLien = array(
"menu1"     => array("Accueil","statique/".Variable_init::$langue."/accueil.html",0,0), //This line
"menu2"     => array("Infos Pratiques","statique/".Variable_init::$langue."/info.html",0,0),
"menu3"     => array("Faire une réservation","statique/".Variable_init::$langue."/reserver.html",0,0),
"menu4"     => array("Pour Nous Joindre","statique/".Variable_init::$langue."/nousJoindre.html",0,0),
"menu5"     => array("Plan du site","statique/".Variable_init::$langue."/plansite.html",0,0)
);
```

And here is my static var declaration from another class:

```
class Variable_init implements iVariable_init{
  public static $langue;
  public static $id_choix;
  public static $id_contenu;
```

Comment: I can't see any syntax errors in Notepad++ when I paste your code, I wonder if the error occurs before that statement. Are there any obvious syntax errors above that line?

Comment: @Ant: Does Notepad++ even use a proper grammar for syntax highlighting or is that merely a bunch of regexes that colorizes something that looks like it might be PHP? That makes quite a big difference in whether syntax highlighting can even detect syntax errors.

Comment: Are there any heredocs used above?  PHP can output some confusing errors when there's an improperly closed heredoc...

Comment: @Johannes: When set to the PHP language, it looks similar to my Eclipse PDT IDE, so as far as my knowledge goes it uses a proper grammar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.properties says:

> They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value**--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Your string concatenations are not constant. The parser doesn't "understand" the [. operator](http://docs.php.net/language.operators.string) in the initialization part and therefore prints `unexpected '.'`

Comment: Thanks alot I am very new to OOP with PHP.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use expressions to initialize class fields.