# Can I do in PHP POO : public $time = time();

Tags: php, variables, time, public

when I do this :

```
public $time = time();
```

I have an error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'.
```

I don't know why, 
Thank you a lots.

Comment: All I see is "PHP POO"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440428/syntax-error-unexpected-expecting)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, as default initializers have to be constant values. In order to do this, assign time in constructor.

```
public $time;
function __construct() {
    $this->time = time();
}
```